# Ocaml: Exception: End_of_file

Tags: ocaml

I want to read a number but when i try to compile it it gives me **Exception: End_of_file** in the line **read_int()**

What am I doing wrong?

```
let k = read_int() ;;
```

```
let  exercicio k=
  Printf.printf "%d\n" k;
;;
```

Comment: How do you compile it? I cannot reproduce this

Comment: @coredump what you mean compile? Sorry i am new to Ocaml. i am in the site https://try.ocamlpro.com/ and when i click the button check it checks the code and says its all alright and then i click eval code to compile and it gives me that error

Comment: the online tool does not have a way to read inputs as far as I know, so when the program executes `read_int()`, it tries to read a value from an input stream which is closed (no input available). That's probably why you have an exception here. You can run an interpreter on a laptop or desktop if you have one, see for example https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/up_and_running.html; if you do so then you will have an interactive toplevel which might is better for testing input/output programs in my opinion. Or you can try other kind of exercises :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an online IDE which accept inputs, check : https://betterocaml.ml .
So far the best you will be able to find on internet. If you want a local install on windows check also https://github.com/gmattis/SimpleOCaml/.

The only issue with betterOCaml is that it doesn't handle infinite while loop, so be sure to save your file before running any programme with a `while` inside.